# JPA/Hibernate manyToMany relation mapping with additional fields

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I have manyToMany relationship mapping and couldn't get it to work. I have read many posts and articles and couldn't figure this one out. If anyone has some idea please share.

I have tried to simplify diagram and code as much.

My database is designed like this:
[image]

My entities look like this (at least final attempt before asking):
**Client:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "client")
public class Client implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "client_id")
    private int id;

    ... other fields
}
```

**Project:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "project")
public class Project implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private ProjectId id;

    ... other fields

    @Embeddable
    class ProjectId implements Serializable {
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "client_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
        private Client client;

        @Column(name = "project_id")
        private int projectId;
    }
}
```

**User:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private UserId id;

    ... other fields

    @Embeddable
    class UserId implements Serializable {
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "client_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
        private Client client;

        @Column(name = "user_id")
        private int userId;
    }
}
```

**ProjectUser:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "project_user")
public class ProjectUser implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private ProjectUserId id;

    ... other fields

    @Embeddable
    class ProjectUserId implements Serializable {
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumn(name = "client_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
        private Client client;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "client_id", referencedColumnName = "client_id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "project_id", referencedColumnName = "project_id", insertable = false, updatable = false) })
        private Project project;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "client_id", referencedColumnName = "client_id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id", insertable = false, updatable = false) })
        private User user;
    }
}
```

Before adding ProjectUser entity everything is working fine.
Now when I'm starting server it says:

> Repeated column in mapping for entity: ProjectUser column: client_id
>   (should be mapped with insert=\"false\" update=\"false\")"}}

So, the question is how do I make this work?

EDIT:
Java application will be mostly REST services providing data. Database design is as is. It has logical sense and most of the business logic will be in database.  We have people with very good DB knowledge working on this and it would not make much sense changing database design because of JPA/Hibernate limitations.

Comment: Start with redesigning your schema. This doesn't really make any sense to me. For example, you have projectId for Project so you don't clientId as part of the primary key. Same with User. What is project_user trying to tell you? If it is just supposed to map Users to Projects and Projects to Users fine, but then what's the clientId for? This all looks like you started with a many-to-many and added Client and stuck clientId into everything. Define what you're trying to do at a more abstract level first.

Comment: I have edited the original question for some clarification. Thank you for the suggestion but I would really want to know if this is possible to map using current database schema.

Comment: "We have people with very good DB knowledge working on this"  -- or not. I can visualize doing this with JPA but it still doesn't make sense so it's not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

The code below will let hibernate create a structure for your entities:

```
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Client client;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "project_client_id", referencedColumnName = "client_id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "project_id", referencedColumnName = "project_id", insertable = false, updatable = false) })
    private Project project;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "user_client_id", referencedColumnName = "client_id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id", insertable = false, updatable = false) })
    private User user;
```

But to make a scheme as on the picture in your question, get rid of all these `EmbeddedId`. Use simple ids and add validation in your code, if you want project and user inside your `ProjectUser` have the same client_id.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have edited original question for some clarification. Your solution with adding two more fields works for hibernate but it seems to much to add fields just to satisfy hibernate. So by the current database situation it seems there is no way to map this. Maybe it's time to reconsider some other persistence solution.

Comment: @hyperion385 of course you can map this! You just need to get rid of `EmbeddedId`, use simple ids.

Comment: Well yes, that's what I've done today. But somehow I feel like this whole object mapping is then loosing it's purpose. But it's better then not working at all :)